Nodejs + Firestore: Error: Did not receive document for "..."
I'm learning firestore and while exploring I came across some strange behaviour, reducing this example to a minimum, here's what I got:
import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";
const firestore = new Firestore({
    databaseId: "(default)"
});
async function main() {
    const document = firestore.doc('test/mydoc');
    await document.set({
        title: 'Welcome to Firestore',
        body: 'Hello World',
    });
    console.log('Entered new data into the document');

    await document.update({
        body: 'My first Firestore app',
    });
    console.log('Updated an existing document');

    const doc = await document.get();
    console.log('Read the document', doc.data());

}

Console output:
Entered new data into the document
Updated an existing document
19 | const document_1 = require("./document");
20 | const util_1 = require("./util");
21 | const logger_1 = require("./logger");
22 | /**
23 |  * A wrapper around BatchGetDocumentsRequest that retries request upon stream
24 |  * failure and returns ordered results.
                              ^
error: Did not receive document for "test/mydoc".


The data is visible in the panel, the record is indeed created
He just can't get all the records. Moreover, I tried doing something like:
firestore.collection('test').get()

and it sometimes gets 1 record, sometimes 0, no connection I can't find. Although there may be more than one record in a collection
I actually copied the firestore example from the gcloud website and it doesn't work as expected

Resolved.
Problem in usage bun

Facing same with Bun. How did you resolved it? use node?

@SagarDevkota yep

If anyone ended up to this post from search, here is the github issue about this: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/9228
